# How to set python version for pip in virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Need to run some project that require installing packages available only for Python 2.7 (I can't change packages). I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 with Python 3.5.3 . I created virtual environment by issuing next command:

```
sudo virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 env
```

Seems like I have version I need:

```
(env) serv@serv:/var/m$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

But when I'm trying to install packages(those only for Python 2.7) it **DOESN'T** look like my virtualenv is using python 2.7 what is more interested, it refers to already installed packages(I supposed that virtualenv won't have any packages,except for some default as pip).

Installing mysql-python (this usually error occurs only when installing from python 3):

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fi75i_pl/mysql-python/
```

When I'm installing package for Python3 - SQLAlchemy:

```
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy in /home/loraserver/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

What can I do to run my code from Python 2.7 environment?

**EDIT 1:** I'm installing mysql-python by:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

This gives me Permission denied.
When I'm trying :

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

It gives me error the same from installing python on python3.

Comment: How are you trying to install packages?

Comment: when you use sudo , i believe you are using the system python version and not your venv's version. skip sudo when installing packages to your venv and it should be fine.

Comment: @user1427258 can't install without sudo.

Comment: Then your venv is in a protected folder, or it's not activated

Comment: then do something like this: (venv) #: sudo /home/xxx/venv/bin/pip install <package_name>

Comment: Do you have a `pip2` binary? Or tried `python2 -m pip install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you created your virtual environment using `sudo`.

This may require you to use `sudo` whenever working inside of your environment, causing your packages to be installed globally.

Try creating a new virtual environment without using `sudo` and then installing your packages from there.

Run the following commands to test it:

`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 testenv`

`source testenv/bin/activate`

`pip install mysql-python`

Comment: Can't create virtualenv because my project folder in /var/project/ directory, so to do that I need to use sudo. Or any other ways?

Comment: @OlegSomov You don't need to create the virtualenv in your project directory. For the sake of solving the problem, try to create the virtualenv in your home directory first. Run `cd ~` and then execute the commands I listed in my answer. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Yes, you're right, package installed successfully. So it doesn't matter where is my virtualenv, I will just run my .py files with full path, right?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @OlegSomov Yes, the location of your virtualenv doesn't matter much, as long as you're working in the appropriate environment. Just make sure to activate the environment before working on your project and you should be fine. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do `sudo rm -rf env` and then (*without* using sudo) start over:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Verify that `which python` shows a python within your project, and similarly for `which pip`. Then:

```
$ pip install mysql-python
```

BTW, there is a nice program named `/usr/bin/env`, so it is usual to name your directory "venv" rather than "env".

Comment: Thank you for advice, I didn't know about env) now I understand why "venv"" better!