# ImportError: No module named can but it's there according to pip list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I have in python the error:

```
ImportError: No module named can
```

but the strange is that when I check it with pip list in the environment all these libraries are installed:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, it tells me that the `can` library is not found, but when I check it with pip list

Comment: use python3 in you call

Comment: Additionally, while it is not required, resizing your console window before taking the screenshot would help in identifying the command you have run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking pip3 (python 3) list, but program working with python 2.7. You need to install the package with pip command.

Comment: See now the screenshot, I have tried with that too.

Comment: @VictorCallejas I think it is related to your virtual env. Therefore please try answers on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752488/how-to-set-python-version-for-pip-in-virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

my issue was missing `__init__` file in the package I want to import